# JQuery hover overlay issue

Tags: jquery, css, overlay

I'm making overlays for about 20-30 items, that when you hover over it the overlay shows, the following code works but is there a way to simplify this so I don't have to repeat this code thirty times?

The overlays are different too, so for for every id, for example #1, there is a seperate overlay #1.beastoverlay too.

So I would have #1 to #30, for example.

```
 $("#1").hover(
  function () {
    $("#1.beastoverlay").show();
  },
  function () {
    $("#1.beastoverlay").hide();
  }
  );


 $("#2").hover(
  function () {
    $("#2.beastoverlay").show();
  },
  function () {
    $("#2.beastoverlay").hide();
  }
  ); 

  ....
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean only the code shown 30 times, or do you have #1 to # 30?

Comment: Can you just please show one sample of your HTML ? please include also the first common parent element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE double or more selectors for same job

```
  var overlay = "#2, #1, #someID ";

  $(overlay).hover(
     function () {
       $(this).next().show();
     },
     function () {
       $(this).next().hide();
     }
  );
```

Comment: The overlays are different too, so for for every id, for example #1, there is a seperate overlay #1.beastoverlay too.

Comment: the code doesn't seem to work properly, you can see it live @ www.slayer.berndvdw.com

Comment: can you try again? :)

Comment: now the item just disappears after hovering, as you can see :p

Comment: I just saw your html ... I think you have strange structure of html ... my last provided answer should work ...

Comment: Doesn't work properly, but thanks for the help anyway :)

Comment: @user3289867 it's crucial for you to share a HTML sample of your code. I think you're going that herder way around

Answer (score 0):

You've got some errors in your code.  It is not valid to use an id more than once on a page.  You have multiple divs with the same id.

Here are some ways to accomplish this correctly:

### Example 1: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/fD2KN/)  (updated with your code)

With jQuery, you can wrap each of your .beast elements and the corresponding .beastoverlay elements in a common class (in the demo I called it .menu-group) and then use the toggle method to show and hide on hover.  Using this method you don't need an id at all (if you want to have one, just make sure to put it on the wrapping element so that it is unique to the page):

```
$('.menu-group').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.beastoverlay').toggle();
});
```

You also need to adjust your css a little to give the absolutely positioned "overlays" a top value and set the wrapper to be positioned relative.

### Example 2: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/fD2KN/1)

You could also do this in css without having to resort to jQuery/Javascript.  The same thing applies here though, you'll need to wrap your .beast and .beastoverlay in a wrapper:

**CSS:**

```
.menu-group:hover div.beastoverlay {
   display: block;
}
```

If you use opacity, height or some other animatable value, you can even do a nice animation on hover.

Answer (score -1):

Try using a for loop:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 1; i < 31; i++) {
        $("#" + i).hover(
            function () {
                $("#" + i + "beastimage").show();
            },
            function () {
                $("#" + i + "beastimage").hide();
            }
        );
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Downvoter should remove the -1 since the OP agreed this is what OP wanted.

Comment: if I implement it actually like this it doesn't show the overlays.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to fix it?

Comment: I want to hide them again once you hover off the item, the original code works as I like, if I remove the .hide part it still doesn't work :'( code live @ slayer.berndvdw.com

Comment: I took a look at your page. A couple of issues. One is that you have the same id: id="1" twice on your page. An id must be unique and you should only use it once. Try changing the first id="1" to id="one" or something similar, then retry. Keep the original for loop with the hide(), I didn't realize hover event points to the "off" state with the second function.

Comment: Changed according your feedback, still not working I guess, did I do something wrong?

Comment: OK, one more thing. You're only trying to show the appropriate "beast" on hover, right? Give the image of the beast a unique id such that when you hover over the div, show the beast image. If this is correct, I will change my code above

Comment: I also just saw this, you need to use $(document).ready(function () {

Comment: Whomever the downvoter is, I challenge you to find something wrong with my code since I was trying to figure out exactly what the OP wanted. After looking at the code on OP's page, I refined my post based on the code I saw. Nothing wrong with my code once I got the full story looking at OP's site. If you have any common courtesy, please explain the downvote.

Comment: Changed/cleaned coding, but overlays not appearing at all now.